# Groupby: Pandas Split-Apply-Combine

Tags: pandas, merge, concatenation

Here is a sport df where,

`ID` is match ID(3 mathes here)

`HG` and `AG` Home/Away goals scored

`Period` is the stage of the game, first quarter, second quarter,...

```
d = {'ID':[121,121,121,121,121,121,343,343,343,343,343,343,343,343,678,678,678,678,678,678,678], 'Period':['1Q','1Q','2Q','2Q','3Q','3Q','1Q','1Q','2Q','2Q',
     '3Q','3Q','4Q','4Q','1Q','1Q','2Q','2Q','3Q','3Q','2Q'],'HG':[0,1,2,3,3,3,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,5,0,1,2,2,3,4,5],
    'AG':[0,0,1,2,2,3,0,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to study the trajectory of goals scored within a sliced portion of df by simply taking the averages of goal score by either team during the selected time portion.

So I split df by row index and apply some function on it.

Let,

```
a = df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[:2]).reset_index(drop=True) 
b = df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[2:5]).reset_index(drop=True) 
c = df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[5:]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

To compute the average goal per each row (rows are some equal and fixed time interval) within each matches, where the length of matches are different, I have to sum the rows and then divide it by all `df.ID.nunique()`.

```
def Goal_Avg(data):
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        return data.loc[:, ['HG','AG']].sum()
```

Then append the new average goal per row columns(for Home/Away) to df. 
Here is how I tried,

First, I created a new row count for `ID` in `df` and `a, b and c` as follow,

```
a['idx'] = a.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()
```

and

```
df['IDX'] = a.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()
```

Then, create new columns with row sum for each ID and eventually obatin the desire `HG_Avg` and `AG_Avg` columns for each match. Which will be the same for same size matches.

```
a_sum = a[['HG','AG']].groupby(a['idx']).apply(g_per)
a_sum.rename(columns={'HG':'HG_sum','AG':'AG_sum'}, inplace=True)
a_sum['HG_Avg'] = a_sum['HG_Sum'] / df.ID.nunique()
a_sum['AG_Avg'] = a_sum['AG_Sum'] / df.ID.nunique()
```

**My problems are**

1- Even after creating the Avg columns for a, b and c, I still  couldnt concat it to original df.

2- The above way looks extremely laborious. Mind you, my data consistes much more than 3 matches.

**Here is the final output**

```
    AG  HG  ID  Period  HG_Avg  AG_Avg  IDX
0   0   0   121     1Q  0.000   0.333   0
1   0   1   121     1Q  0.667   1.000   1
2   1   2   121     2Q  1.667   1.333   2
3   2   3   121     2Q  2.333   2.000   3
4   2   3   121     3Q  3.000   2.667   4
5   3   3   121     3Q  3.667   3.000   5
6   0   0   343     1Q  0.000   0.333   0
7   1   0   343     1Q  0.667   1.000   1
8   1   1   343     2Q  1.667   1.333   2
9   2   2   343     2Q  2.333   2.000   3
10  3   3   343     3Q  3.000   2.667   4
11  3   4   343     3Q  3.667   3.000   5
12  4   4   343     4Q  3.000   2.667   6
13  4   5   343     4Q  1.667   1.333   7
14  1   0   678     1Q  0.000   0.333   0
15  2   1   678     1Q  0.667   1.000   1
16  2   2   678     2Q  1.667   1.333   2
17  2   2   678     2Q  2.333   2.000   3
18  3   3   678     3Q  3.000   2.667   4
19  3   4   678     3Q  3.667   3.000   5
20  4   5   678     2Q  3.000   2.667   6
```

Comment: why you need split ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen, I'm studying the nature of goals scored within a given interval.

Answer (score 1):

First create the additional key by using `cumcount` and `cut` , then you have two key for `groupby`

```
df['NewKey']=pd.cut(df.groupby('ID').cumcount(),[-1,2,5,np.inf])
df.groupby(['ID','NewKey']).apply(yourfunc here)
```